# Does a program to convert "foo:blah" to JSON exist?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, string-parsing

I would like to convert a human-readable list such as this:

```
Enabled: No
Server: localhost
Port: 8888
Authenticated Proxy Enabled: 0
```

... into an object, preferably sanitized as JSON, such as this:

```
{
    "Enabled": "No",
    "Server": "localhost",
    "Port": 8888,
    "Authenticated Proxy Enabled": 0
}
```

But I expect that implementing this directly would lead to hard-to-track bugs.

I am working on a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) app which happens to make use of some built in networking tools on OS X via [shelljs](https://github.com/arturadib/shelljs). This is where the list comes from and I simply need to process it.

Here is a command you can run from Terminal easily to see roughly what I see:

```
networksetup -getwebproxy Wi-Fi
```

Assuming you have a "network service" called Wi-Fi, that should spit out a list like the one above.

I would prefer numbers parsed as numbers, not strings. But I could live without that.

**Please note:** I am specifically looking to avoid re-inventing the wheel. Doing this myself would be relatively easy, but I want to find a small module for this mundane nuance of processing the data. I am asking to list projects which do this already.

This problem is difficult to search for.

Comment: That first one looks like it could be YAML. So, find a YAML parser and then encode the result in JSON. Could be a single line of code.

Comment: easy with regex. in reality the syntax being parsed is so trivial that even without any tools the code wont be over 10 lines thus I dont see the big need to avoid maintaining or reinventing it.

Comment: @deceze that seems to be the ticket. I was not familiar with YAML syntax, so learned something new. If you post an answer based on that, with a few links for the benefit of others, I'll accept it.

Comment: Why would the maintenance and update requirements of a library be easier than that of an 8 line function? Should the port number stay a string or be converted to a number?

Comment: `.split("\n").reduce(function(a,b){b=b.split(/\:\s*/);a[b[0]]=b[1];return a;},{})`

Comment: Throwing my opinion into the pot: it's certainly correct that you don't necessarily need a YAML parser at all, this is pretty trivial to parse manually. However, it's worth thinking beyond "strings" and abstract this kind of thing away. If there's an existing serialisation format that fits your requirements, is very expressive and powerful, and has good support in the form of robust libraries, then just use it instead of futzing around with manual string manipulation. Being able to think in terms of "transforming one serialisation format into another" is worth adding another library.

Comment: @dandavis—except the OP wants "*…numbers parsed as numbers…*" so maybe `a[b[0]]=isNaN(Number(b[1]))? b[1]:Number(b[1])`.

Comment: @RobG: dang, i wanted it to fit in one comment line... even with a fork, it's more preferable to me than 40k+ lines of parsing code that's not needed for the job. i guess some folks figure "why write 2 lines when i can write 1  and add 2800+ lines someone else wrote for me?"

Comment: @RobG It's not good to generalise like that. First of all, we're apparently talking about a nodejs app here; code size is hardly an issue there. Secondly, I'm currently working on an SPA which literally contains 1.5 MBs of libraries; but it has a very special purpose, is doing very complex things, and the page is intended to stay up all day in the browser, so the initial load time doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @dandavis I have reasons. What about tests, documentation, etc.? This is functionality my app's architecture should *not* be responsible for. If delegating this to a library means "2800+ lines", then either this problem is really complex or there is a problem with the library and I won't use it. Now that I know what to search for, I can search for the most minimalist module that serves my needs. If [sindresorhus](https://github.com/sindresorhus "Sindre makes minimalist modules.") made one, I would use it. Thanks deceze.

Comment: the YAML parser is 2800 lines. it's all opinions anyway, getting it working is the main thing...

Comment: @deceze—fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first snippet could easily be [YAML](http://yaml.org), so get a [YAML parser](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml), decode the YAML and encode it into JSON:

```
JSON.stringify(yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('example.yml', 'utf8')))
```